# Does operator overloading [] automatically overload arithmetics as well?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

Say I have a class `MyOwnArray` and as the name suggests, I want to make my own
  array. I found out that I can return the indexed value by operator overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyOwnArray {

private:
    int arr[3];

public:
    MyOwnArray() {
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1] = 2;
        arr[2] = 3;
    }

    int &operator[](int i) {    // Also overload +, +=, etc?
        return arr[i];          // and I'm only returning the value
                                // but it seems to modify when using "+="
                                // as demonstrated in main()
    }

};


int main() {

    MyOwnArray a;       // my own array

    cout << a[0];       // outputs "1".
    a[0] += a[2];       // Not expecting this to work, but it does
    cout << a[0];       // outputs "4"

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that `cout << a[0]` outputs the value `1`.
I was not expecting that I could do things like `a[0] += 1`. Does operator overloading `[]` automatically overload arithmetics as well?
Most importantly: why does `a[0]` get modified when I simply return the value in
this function?

```
int &operator[](int i) {    // Also overload +, +=, etc?
        return arr[i];          // and I'm only returning the value
                                // but it seems to modify when using "+="
                                // as demonstrated in main()
}
```

Comment: The code isn’t returning a value. It’s returning a **reference** to a value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: Make the operator return a `const` reference (e.g. `const int &operator[](int i) {return arr[i];}`) and you will get the consequences you expect from your `main()` function  (the `a[0] += a[2]` will not compile).